# How would I make a list case insensitive while passing it to a function in Python

Tags: python

Now develop a function called count_this_word_in_all_tweets that takes as arguments a list of tweets and a word and it would find the number of occurrence of the word in all tweets in the list. The function should use list comprehension and the function count_this_word_in_this_tweet defined earlier to accomplish its task.

So I have this as my count_this_word_in_this_tweet function and it works like its supposed too.

```
def count_this_word_in_this_tweet(data, word):
    data.islower()
    word.islower()
    splitwords = data.split()
    count = splitwords.count(word)
    return count
```

My other function is

```
def count_this_word_in_all_tweets(data, word):
    count = [count_this_word_in_this_tweet(s,word) for s in  data]
    total = sum(count)
    return total
```

But this second one is not case insensitive.  I tried to search for movie and I get 140 results and I search for Movie and I get 14.  I'm not sure why this second function is not case insensitive since it is calling a function that is.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`islower()` only checks if the value of a string is all lowercase.

> str.islower()
>
> > Return True if all cased characters 4 in the string are lowercase and there is at least one cased character, False otherwise.

You're looking for `lower()`.

> str.lower()
>
> > Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters 4 converted to lowercase.
> >
> > The lowercasing algorithm used is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard.

```
test = 'StRiNG'
>>> test.islower()
False
>>> test.lower()
'string'
>>>
```

You would need to set your data to `lower()`

```
data = data.lower()
word = word.lower()
```

Based on your example;

```
data = ['DawnofthePlanetoftheApes - Movie Reviews, Movie Rating, Trailers, Posters | MovieMagik http:t.co/lYSGCB8jXR via @moviemagikin Saw the new Planet of the Apes. Best one since the original with way better effects! #DawnofthePlanetoftheApes I could say Im watching Planet of the Apes (1968) as a countdown to #DawnofthePlanetoftheApes - but really, I could watch it any time.']

word = 'movie'

def count_me(data, word):
    data = data.lower()
    word = word.lower()
    splitwords = data.split()
    count = splitwords.count(word)
    return count

def lets_roll(data, word):
    count = [count_me(s, word) for s in data]
    total = sum(count)
    return total

>>> lets_roll(data, word)
#2
```

[`islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower)

[`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

Comment: Ok but even if I change the def count_this_word_in_this_tweet(data, word):
    data.islower()
    word.islower() to .lower, it still doesn't fix the problem.  Would I have to change the list and word to lower in the other one too?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your input for `data` and `word`?

Comment: data is a list of tweets that have been edited.  the word is just Movie.  My print statement is  print (count_this_word_in_all_tweets(tweets[:], "Movie"))

Comment: If data is a list. Try this, `data = [word.lower() for word in data]`

Comment: That does work if I do it for my second function.  I can't do that for the first because I'm splitting the data

Comment: Im going to need some examples of your `data` input before the first function if you want me to assist any further.

Comment: tweets = [extract_tweet(data) for data in tweets_and_more]

    
print ("\n")

print ("\n\n".join(tweets[:3]))


#DawnofthePlanetoftheApes - Movie Reviews, Movie Rating, Trailers, Posters | MovieMagik http:t.co/lYSGCB8jXR via @moviemagikin


Saw the new Planet of the Apes.  Best one since the original with way better effects!  #DawnofthePlanetoftheApes

I could say I'm watching Planet of the Apes (1968) as a countdown to #DawnofthePlanetoftheApes - but really, I could watch it any time.

That is really messy

Comment: @BillAsif Try setting `data = data.lower()` and `word = word.lower()` in your top function, replacing `data.islower()` and `word.islower()`

Comment: I also updated answer to add functioning code based off your example.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.